# sfdx creates huge log files in $HOME/.sf/sf.log

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-error

Deploying using sfdx can create up to remaining storage space logs in single deploy (over 100GB). The whole log file usually consist of one entry repeated as many times as possible:

```
{"name":"sf","hostname":"<--redacted-->","pid":15580,"level":60,"errno":-32,"code":"EPIPE","syscall":"write","msg":"","time":"2022-08-17T09:15:49.411Z","v":0}
```

How to prevent this? `"level":60` suggests `fatal` level, so changing SFDX_LOG_LEVEL probably wont help.
What does `"errno":-32` means?

This is run on a machine that I don't have direct access to, so i can't check sfdx version or delete the log file right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found what the problem was.
The wider context is that sfdx was run in GitLab runner (CI).

From what i found, when pipeline job is canceled SIGKILL is sent to an executing process and sfdx really don't like it.

The solution is to never cancel a job from GitLab. For us it usually mean canceling validation/deployment from salesforce UI. Then pipeline fails instead of being cancelled.